# What is wallet.dat.gpg?

Tags: wallet.dat

I'm trying to convince myself that I'm backing up my wallet correctly. I am told my private keys are in the wallet.dat file, but **what is wallet.dat.gpg**? It's [not listed here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory).

Answer (score 1):

The `.gpg` file extension is often used to indicate a [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) encrypted file. Somebody, or something, at some time, probably made an encrypted copy of your `wallet.dat` file and named it `wallet.dat.gpg`.

Comment: Well it wasn't me manually. I use bitcoin-qt. The wallet should be encrypted already (I have a padlock icon) so I don't understand where gpg comes into it. My question is who/what is the "somebody or something".